# Additional /admin appears when i click on a link

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to move a website that i have not implemented to another host. After uploading everything the frontend of the website works ok. But in the admin section when i click on a link there is a problem with the url. An additional /admin appears to every link and that results to a 404 error.

The problem is that i cannot intervene in the code since it is encoded with IonCube.

Does someone has an idea about what my be the source of this issue?

There is no htaccess file, yet. Do you believe that i should create one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"Does someone has an idea about what my be the source of this issue?"* - Yeah, the operative word here being "source" as in "source code" which "you" have.

Comment: please paste your `htaccess` code on your question.

Comment: try using jquery, a[href*='admin'] selector

Comment: the code is encrypted, i cannot see it.

Comment: *"There is no htaccess file, yet. Do you believe that i should create one?"* - I'd say yes and use ErrorDocument 404 /yourpage.xxx

Comment: i haven't created an htaccess file yet.

Comment: so what are you asking us then? to create it for you?

Comment: Maybe i was not clear enough about my problem. When i click on a link or a button in the admin area the url is ../admin/admin/products.php but the correct one is ../admin/products.php . Is there a way using an htaccess file to solve this issue?

Comment: yes, you need a rewrite/redirection rule then

Comment: Like this? RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^/admin/admin/?$    ^/admin/?$